# Adding a gradient to a tableview hides content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, cagradientlayer

I have a tableview and it works well. But I have to add gradient on background. I did it with this code in viewDidLoad:

```
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
let color1 = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor as CGColorRef
let color2 = UIColor.redColor().CGColor as CGColorRef
gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

But now I don't see any content of my tableview.

Comment: Instead of using `self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)`, try `self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex:0)`.

Comment: @SauvikDolui yeah, it works but with a simple correction. `self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex:0)` instead of `self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex:0). Also for **Swift 3** atIndex has just become at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a background gradient to be appropriately configured you can use `backgroundView` property of `UITableView` and a View with `CAGradientLayer`. A resulting code (in Swift 3) will be:

```
/* A small UIView subclass displaying gradient */

class GradientView: UIView {

    /* Overriding default layer class to use CAGradientLayer */
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    /* Handy accessor to avoid unnecessary casting */
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }

    /* Public properties to manipulate colors */
    public var fromColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            var currentColors = gradientLayer.colors
            currentColors![0] = fromColor.cgColor
            gradientLayer.colors = currentColors
        }
    }

    public var toColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue {
        didSet {
            var currentColors = gradientLayer.colors
            currentColors![1] = toColor.cgColor
            gradientLayer.colors = currentColors
        }
    }

    /* Initializers overriding to have appropriately configured layer after creation */
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        gradientLayer.colors = [fromColor.cgColor, toColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        gradientLayer.colors = [fromColor.cgColor, toColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    }
}


/* Code that should be called in viewDidLoad method */

class MyViewController: UITableViewController {

    /* ... */

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.backgroundView = GradientView()
    }

    /* ... */

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It actually works. Only one thing, sorry, how to make it horizontal?

Comment: You're welcome! Added 2 lines to each initializer that configure horizontal gradient direction.

Comment: it will give me error??? on below function....? for swift 3:

    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }

-> Could not cast value of type 'CALayer' (0x10ac29de8) to 'CAGradientLayer' (0x10ac2a838).